# How to extract specific keys using Jora in JSON Discovery Report

Tags: json, jora

When creating a JSON Discovery report using jora query language https://github.com/discoveryjs/jora

how to extract only the keys that I am interested in and create a new array where objects only have specified key?

Example:

```
[
    {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3},
    {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3},
    {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3}
]
```

To:

```
[
    {foo: 1},
    {foo: 1},
    {foo: 1}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You can specify required keys like this:

```
.({foo})
```

2) To rename a key, you can do this:

```
.({a: foo})
```

Result:

```
[
    {a: 1},
    {a: 1},
    {a: 1}
]
```